# java.lang.ClassCastException When attempting to print or reference int[] and int in storage class

Tags: java, data-structures, classcastexception

I have a simple database-like project that is meant to put usernames and encrypted passwords in a `HashMap` and, in a separate `HashMap`, associate usernames and a storage object (called `PasswordData`) which contains an integer array (this is used as a key by the encryption library) and an integer that is also used by the library. This all works well, but the problem comes in a secondary function of the code. I have a few methods dedicated to copying the `HashMap`s into files which can latter be read and the information inside the files can be restored in the `HashMap`. However, when trying to do anything with the variables inside `PasswordData`, I get a the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to webappserver.PasswordData".

I found that no matter what I was trying to do with said variables, the JVM claimed I was attempting to cast the storage class to String. If I am missing any vital information, please inform me and I will try to edit in anything that may be required.

The storage class:

```
public class PasswordData{
    public int[] key;
    public int  index;
    PasswordData(int[] key, int index){
        this.key = key;
        this.index = index;
    }
    public int[] returnKey(){
        return key;
    }
    public int returnIndex(){
        return index;
    }
}
```

Bugged Method:

```
public void writeFilePassData(HashMap passData,  String fileName) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> usersArrayList = new ArrayList<>(passData.keySet());
    ArrayList<PasswordData> passwordDataArrayList = new ArrayList<> (passData.values());
    BufferedWriter save = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    for(int i =0; i< usersArrayList .size(); i++){
        int[] ex = passwordDataArrayList .get(i).returnKey();
        save.write(usersArrayList .get(i) + '\n');
        save.write(ex.toString());
        save.write(passwordDataArrayList .get(i).returnIndex().toString());
    }
    save.close();
}
```

Note: `printStackTrace` flags the first line of the for statement as the location of the `ClassCastException`, but removing in it only resulted in the second statement now amended to `Save.write(passwordDataArrayList.get(i).returnKey().toString());` returning the same error.

Comment: PasswordData doesn't appear to have a `get(int i)` method. You may be posting incomplete code, hard to tell without better code, best if it were a [mcve].

Comment: I just realized I had named both the ArrayList and the storage class the same thing; I'll fix that right away.

Comment: Your variable names are ***very*** confusing, and you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: I apologize for the messy code. I believe changed the snippets of code to align with the naming conventions.

Comment: If you don't get an answer in a few hours, again consider creating a valid [mcve], and then comment back to me when/if you do

Comment: I have to go to sleep pretty soon, so I'll have to make one tomorrow. Thank you for all of the advice.

Comment: You'll have to post how you populate `passData` because evidently you managed to put Strings as the values which isn't caught until the `get`.

Comment: Are you able to modify the code to include type parameters for the HashMap (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)?  Without seeing more code, my best guess is that one or more of the values being put into `passData` is actually a String elsewhere in the code.  The error occurs on the line you pointed out because it's the first place you're trying to use the value.

Comment: I figured it out. While I was constructing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, I realized I have been passing the incorrect HashMap via parameters to the function. Thanks to both of you for the assistance.